# Measures to improve execution time of a database query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, twitter-bootstrap

**Using twitter bootstrap typeahead**

I have given path of a php page "getItems.php" in **source** of typeahead.

**getItems.php** fetches the results from 3 tables :-

```
SELECT pm . * , p.pname, pc.cid
FROM products p, products_mrp pm, products_category pc
WHERE p.pid = pm.pid
AND p.pid = pc.pid
AND p.pname like '%$text%' limit 7
```

It is taking about 22 seconds to execute this query.

- Table **products** has 654 rows
- Table **products_category** has 629 rows
- Table **products_mrp** has 712 rows

What can I do to reduce the fetching time? Because 22 seconds waiting for an autocomplete is meaningless.

Comment: There should probably be a JOIN in that query.. are you actually getting the correct results??

Comment: Yes i am getting correct results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do you have indexes set on your tables? That’s the absolute simplest way to improve DB speed. [Read up on the details here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes/).

I recommend using the [MySQL Tuning Primer Script located here](https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer). Very easy to use & the recommendations are pretty spot on.

Depending on your setup you might need to learn how to performance tune by hand—meaning you learn to interpret MySQL output yourself and act on it—but this script works quite well for 95% of the setups I have ever used them on.  The other 5% are database idiosyncratic setups that required more custom care.  I highly recommend tutorials like [this one on the MySQL performance blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/09/20/innodb-performance-optimization-basics-updated/).

Answer (score 0):

Hope you did some goggling regarding this question.
please refer below document and make sure to enter the database type.
[4 Query Optimizer Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_optcncpt.htm#TGSQL192)

Answer (score 0):

Need more info...

SHOW CREATE TABLE for each table.

Are the various xid's the PRIMARY KEYs in each table?  If they are not (nor any other type of index), then that would explain the sluggishness.

It is cleaner to use explicit JOINs, not "comma join":

```
FROM products p
JOIN products_mrp pm ON p.pid = pm.pid
JOIN products_category pc ON p.pid = pc.pid
```